# Accessing a local variable/method within a nested require blocks?

Tags: dojo, requirejs, amd

I am not finding in the documentation how to access a local variable of method of the class from within a nested require blocks.

```
    declare( "Clust", StrictIntHashMap,
    {       
        constructor : function()
        {

        },

        cust : function( custId )
        {
            return this.get( custId );
        },

        add : function( custObject )
        {
            this.set( custObject.custId, custObject );
        },

        reloadThecustses : function()
        {
            that = this;
            require( [ 'inst/DataExtractor', 'inst/ClustTree' ], function ( de, theTree ) 
            {

                de.getPlainJSON( Commandz.COMMAND_GET_CUSTS,
                function ( dataR )
                { 
                    that.add( new Customer( dataR.root[c] ) ); // not working
                    this.cust( 0 ); // not working

                    theTree.refreshTheData( dataR.root );

                } );

            } );
        }


    } );    

    return Clust;
```

- How to access the method "add" of the class from within the require block ?
- How to access the local variable "that" from within the require block ?

Comment: What exact test code do you run to declare that it is "not working"?

Comment: Custs.js:60 Uncaught ReferenceError: that is not defined, and if i remove it and replace it as "this.add( whatever )" it goes "Custs.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined"

Comment: But `that` is defined in your code. You define it with `that = this`. You should really have `var that = this` because without `var` you are putting it in the global space, which is bad coding, but it *is* defined.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access variables defined in the parent scope when using `require`, since it's equivalent to just having a child scope.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to access, but I assume it's the `Clust` instance.

Would this code work for you?

```
declare( "Clust", StrictIntHashMap, {       
    constructor : function() {
    },
    cust : function( custId ) {
        return this.get( custId );
    },
    add : function( custObject ) {
        this.set( custObject.custId, custObject );
    },
    reloadThecustses : function() {
      var clustInstance = this;
      require( [ 'inst/DataExtractor', 'inst/ClustTree' ], 
       function ( de, theTree ) {
         de.getPlainJSON( Commandz.COMMAND_GET_CUSTS, function ( dataR ) { 
           clustInstance.add( new Customer( dataR.root[c] ) ); 
           clustInstance.cust( 0 ); 
           theTree.refreshTheData( dataR.root );
         });
     });
   }
});    

return Clust;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is caused by having the wrong context in the callback function to `getPlainJSON`. [`dojo.hitch()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch) will fix this:

```
    reloadThecustses : function()
    {
        require( [ 'inst/DataExtractor', 'inst/ClustTree', 'dojo/_base/lang' ], function ( de, theTree, lang )
        {
            de.getPlainJSON( Commandz.COMMAND_GET_CUSTS,
            lang.hitch( function ( dataR )
            {
                this.add( new Customer( dataR.root[c] ) ); // not working
                this.cust( 0 ); // not working

                theTree.refreshTheData( dataR.root );

            }, this )
        } );
    }
```